# List binding issue in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Firstly I would like to disclose that I am a new developer and just starting out coding with Xamarin and C sharp.

I have setup a list on locations in a list. I have two views, a list view page and a detailed page of the list views. All the Binding elements in this list are accessible and work fine in the list view and then when clicked upon they also display in the detailed view. The issue is that I have also added a clicked property with the others in the list and as such in the model too. This click property aims to handle a button click in the detail page which in turn will play an audio file. After I run the code their are no errors, the audio just doesn't play at all.

please see the following code for a better insight into what im faced with:

**Tourpage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class ToursPage : ContentPage
{
    async public void Handle_ItemSelected(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)

    {
        if (e.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        var location = e.SelectedItem as Location;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ToursDetail(location));
        listView.SelectedItem = null;

    }

    public ToursPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        listView.ItemsSource = new List<Location>{

        new Location
        {
            Name = "Kilkenny Castle",
            Description = "This is the description Kilkenny Castle is simply dummy text of the printing and type setting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic ",
            ImageUrl = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/Kilkenny_castle.jpg",
            Clicked = "Handle_Clicked1"
        },
        new Location
        {
            Name = "Butler House",
            Description = "This is the description Kilkenny Castle is simply dummy text of the printing and type setting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic ",
            ImageUrl = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/Kilkenny_castle.jpg",
            Clicked = "Handle_Clicked2"
        }
        };
```

**ToursDetail.xaml**

```
    <StackLayout>
    <Image Source = "{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
    <Label Text = "{Binding Description}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
    <Button Text = "Play" Command="{Binding Clicked}"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

**ToursDetail.xaml.cs** This is where the button click is handled

```
 public partial class ToursDetail : ContentPage
{

    public ToursDetail(Location location)
    {
        if (location == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        BindingContext = location;

        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Handle_Clicked1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        DependencyService.Get<IAudio>().Play_Pause("http://www.hochmuth.com/mp3/Haydn_Cello_Concerto_D-1.mp3");
    }
```

**Model**

```
namespace CustomRenderer.Models
{
public class Location
{
    public string Name { get; set; }  
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string Clicked { get; set; }


}
}
```

Now what is also important to note is the if I change the code in **ToursDetail.xaml** file to the following:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Image Source = "{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
    <Label Text = "{Binding Description}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
    <Button Text = "Play" Clicked= "Handle_Clicked1"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

Then the audio plays fine. So therefore this type of setup won't work for me because I need the list selection to bind the location audio based on that selection rather than just for one as I have set here. Any help on how to achieve the workaround for this would be most grateful. I have been going around in circles trying to resolve this and find a solution.

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 1):

I'm new too, but I might have added 'Clicked' as public Command member in a View Model:

```
public class ToursDetailViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public Location location { get; set; }
    public Command ClickedCommand { get; set; }
    ...
```

Then in the ViewModel constructor, attach the command with any other logic you may need around the particular location - ie pass the sound file path in parameter to the function:

```
public ToursDetailViewModel(Location loc = null)
{
    location = loc;
    ClickedCommand = new Command(async () => await Handle_Clicked1(loc.soundpath));
```

And so NOW :

```
ToursDetailViewModel viewModel;
public ToursDetail(Location location)
{
    if (location == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    BindingContext = this.viewModel = new ToursDetailViewModel(location);
```

and finally:

```
<Label Text = "{Binding location.Description}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
<Button Text = "Play" Command="{Binding ClickedCommand}"/>
```

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your response. Im having difficulty understanding how I could implement this based on what I have to be honest. Like for example how do I set private void Handle_Clicked1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            DependencyService.Get<IAudio>().Play_Pause("http://www.hochmuth.com/mp3/Haydn_Cello_Concerto_D-1.mp3");
        }         in to this like you said:   Handle_Clicked1(loc.soundpath)  Im unsure how I will set this sound path.

Comment: basically setup a new class and called it ToursDetailViewModel in my model folder. Is the correct? I then set the following "public Location location { get; set; }
    public Command ClickedCommand { get; set; }" and "public ToursDetailViewModel(Location loc = null)
{
    location = loc;
    ClickedCommand = new Command(async () => await Handle_Clicked1(loc.soundpath));" it its constructor. Is that part correct? then "ToursDetailViewModel viewModel;" is this also a new page or what am I setting up here. Sorry Im just lost as to what way to structure this.

Comment: ok - the ToursDetailViewModel is a separate class. I have a separate ViewModels folder for it. If you're using Visual Studio 2017 (even the free community version), just create a new multiplatform 'Forms App' project and it will show you the directory layout and file structures for most of this. The Handle_Clicked1 would just handle parameters normally, in this case a string for path of the sound file, and then just pass that param to .Play_Pause( -param- ). But since the 'Location' is available in the same ViewModel - don't bother passing an arg - just access location.SoundPath

Comment: Ok thanks again for the input. the location.Soundpath does that assume that I have the audio file locally? Because I am using a http link and I am unsure how I will implement that. Could you for example show me how this DependencyService.Get<IAudio>().Play_Pause("http://www.hochmuth.com/mp3/Haydn_Cello_Concerto_D-1.mp3"); can be implemented into the SoundPath. Iv no idea how I will do this exactly. Thanks Again

Comment: I thought you wanted a different audio file for each location? If so, that path belongs as a property of your location. After you load all locations, and select a location, the appropriate audio file URI comes with it and the ViewModel will play it. The ViewModel _should not care_ what audio file will play. You had it as a URI above, and so I haven't altered that requirement. If you hard code the URI in your Handle_Clicked1 function, you will only ever play that one file, right? Associate to the location, and it's dynamically set forever.

Comment: Even if the audio to play is not variated by location, set a configuration in another table and also retrieve such config settings. I would tend not to hard code such things.

Comment: Yes I do wish to have different audio per location. Im completely lost now to be honest Robert . where it has Soundpath (Im assuming you wish to put the path of where the file is here?) do I do the following: Handle_Clicked1(loc.http://www.hochmuth.com/mp3/Haydn_Cello_Concerto_D-1.mp3));  When I said I was a new developer I pretty much haven't coded in any other code.

Comment: when you say above "just access location.SoundPath" do I leave that as is or what do I set this as? Its at this point Im not sure what to put. also do I leave this as is so that I can access the dependency service :  private void Handle_Clicked1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        DependencyService.Get<IAudio>().Play_Pause("http://www.hochmuth.com/mp3/Haydn_Cello_Concerto_D-1.mp3");
    }

Comment: I am getting an error for soundPath. So what does one set for this? Thanks

Comment: path is a bit of a misnomer - sorry. In your Location object add a member called AudioURI. That member will hold the http 'path' or URI to the online resource, and not some local file. When ever I wrote 'path', replace that with URI and whenever you saw soundpath, replace that with AudioURI. I never intended for any local audio file.

Comment: Stop using any hard coded 'URI'. Why would you even attempt something like "loc.hochmuth.com/mp3/Haydn_Cello_Concerto_D-1.mp3"? Stop and think. Really. You have to set up your Location object at some point. When you bind that object to your screen, do you do _location.Triesenberg_ or _location.Name_? When you save information in a variable, just retrieve it. So, when you create your location object, put "http://www.hochmuth.com/mp3/Haydn_Cello_Concerto_D-1.mp3" into location.AudioURI - when you want to play it, it becomes DependencyService.Get<IAudio>().Play_Pause(location.AudioURI); right?